# Copy the contents of a cell if the value of another cell is equal to a third

Tags: vba, excel

I have updated the document [Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwla2SIjeXjgYjRDTE90dU9DRTA/edit?usp=sharing)

The problem, with a clearer explanation, is; On my C-D-E-F tab I have , in E12:E14, The VIP numbers. Next cell, F12:F14, labeled "Bulk" are empty. In these cells I want the value from the Data tab, cells T58 in F12, T61 in F13, and T64 in F14.

The bad news is this column will change every day with updated values, the good news is that the order will stay the same. So the lowest VIP tag *16001669*, will be the first VIP total, middle is next, and last is last.

Then, I need the number of "Caged Tote's", under the number copied to the C-D-E-F tab, copied to the next cell.

Right now I have:

```
   E11       F11    G11
  VIP       Bulk   Totes
16001669    
16001670
16001671
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
    E11       F11    G11
  VIP       Bulk   Totes
16001669      4       1
16001670      1       1
16001671      4       1
```

Comment: Do share the doc on google drive.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwla2SIjeXjgYjRDTE90dU9DRTA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user2727453  -I'm having problems relating the question to the spreadsheet!

Comment: @user2727453 one thing I did notice as an aside is that in Sheet8 you have some code - it looks like you should set up a sub-routine with input parameters as there seems to be a lot of repeated code

Comment: I requested help on this forum to get the code, then modified it the best I could to get it to produce the desired result. I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do it, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use a VLookup formula?

=vlookup(value_looking for, range_table_to_look_in, column_to_return, false)

Failing that, if you're trying to achive in code (and can't just use application worksheetfunction vlookup() ) use the find method of range object.

Let rgSearch = the cell with the value you're looking for= 1234, 4567 etc, rgSearchList = the first column of that table you've listed, intCol = the column you want to return, i.e. three

```vb
Function GetThingy(rgSearch as range, rgSearchList as range, intCol as integer) as range

    set rgMatch = rgSearchList.find(rgSearch.value, rgSearchList.cells(1,1), xlValues, xlWhole)

    if not rgMatch is nothing then 'i.e. "if found"
        GetThingy = rgMatch.offset(0, intCol - 1) ' have to remove one because this is an offset from rgMatch, not an absolute from left edge
    else
        GetThingy = nothing
    end if
end function
```

Comment: Having now looking at your Google doc, I'm guessing your problem is more complicated :) Can you explain using your document as a reference what result you're wanting?

Comment: Sure, The data tab, T45 and down is the information I need added under the HC totals box on the C-D-E-F Tab. On Data, hit the calculate button. It produces a list, I want the cell on the C-D-E-F tab, E12, to list the first VIP. 16001669. Under Bulk, Cell F12, I want the total associated with 16001669 on the Data tab, cell T58, which is 4. On G12, Under tote. I want the number 1 for the caged tote associated with the number, on Data, Cell T59.   This information changes every day.